# CodeIgniter Return Null Value In database result

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

I'm New to CodeIgniter.
I am using `Sakila` database for learning purpose..

and i'm trying to get `Title`,`description`, from `film table`,
`language name` from `language table`, and `category name` from `category` table,

i query

```
    $this->db->select(' f.film_id,
                        f.language_id,
                        f.title,
                        f.description,
                        l.name AS language,
                        c.name AS category,
                        fc.film_id AS fc
                        ');
    $this->db->from('film AS f');
    $this->db->join('language AS l', 'l.language_id=f.language_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('film_category AS fc', 'f.film_id=fc.film_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('category AS c', 'c.category_id=fc.film_id', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by('f.film_id','desc')->limit($num,$start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

and i got desired result except category name. in database cmd works fine and return correct`category name` but in `codeigniter` i return `null` for `cartegory name..`

why it's happened ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have error in `ON` Clause...
There is no Column named `film_id` in `category table` inside `sakila` database.

change

```
$this->db->join('category AS c', 'c.category_id=fc.category_id', 'left');
```

and you are done...

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your alias.
Your are using "fc" for both a table and a field

```
fc.film_id AS fc

$this->db->join('film_category AS fc', 'f.film_id=fc.film_id', 'left');
```

Change one of the alias and you should be ok.